# Deleting content of the folder using VC++

Tags: file, visual-c++

I am using the following code to create a directory using the following code.

> TCHAR dir_path[] = TEXT("C:\Users\Temp\abc");
>                    if (!CreateDirectory(dir_path,NULL)) {
>                    }
>                    else
>                    {
>                     //directory already exists
>                     }

I want to add the logic to delete all the content of the folder(Files and folders recursively if any are there) if the folder C:\Users\Temp\abc already exists.

Any idea how I can delete the content of the folder recursively?

Thanks in Advance,
Azeem

I am new to this site. Apologies in advance if I am mistaken anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly find the entries in the directory:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

See if they are directory or not:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If yes, change to it and call the function again http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Then delete it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx